# Cannot find referrals section in branch.io SDK

Tags: ios, branch.io, referrals

My dashboard doesn't have an option to set reward rules. It should have been under channels and links but cannot see it.

Dashboard image:

[image: Dashboard image link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Branch is revamping the referrals system. It is not reflecting on your dashboard for the same reason.

Please check on this link via your branch account : https://dashboard.branch.io/referrals

It will show up the referrals section on your dashboard. Please set a reward rule as per your use and refresh the page. 
The referrals tab will now be visible for you.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Thanks ... Also is there a documentation i can refer for implementation in iOS and any ETA by when it will be revamped?

Comment: Branch should show some message for this on the dashboard. Was stuck on this for last 2 days, thanks for the help